# Different select colors for different list view items

Tags: java, android, listview, user-interface

I have the following requirements:

- different colors for different list view items
- colors are specified dynamically in the code
- color should only be shown if the list view item is pressed/selected
- color of the list view item should not change permanently

For whatever reasons it seems not to be as straight forward as I thought. The only solution that goes at least a little bit in the right direction is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16978159/658718

The caveat is, that this does not change the on select color, but changes the background color permanently, plus it already changes the background color for list view items if you scroll down a bit.

How can I approach this?

Comment: Mantain falg for color like integer(red : 1, blue : 2 .etc..)...store that values in adapter or array whatever you have used, in item click get that value... depend on that value show color.. simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty here is that pressed/checked color is dynamic. You cannot use static xml color-state-list. But you can create [ColorStateList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html) by code. Here is how to do that.

You just have to implement the ListAdapter :

```
private class MyListAdapter implements ListAdapter{

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView!=null){
             CheckedTextView textView = (CheckedTextView)convertView;
             textView.setText("the text for item "+position);
             textView.setTextColor(makeColorStateListForItem(position));
             return textView;
        }else{
             CheckedTextView textView = new CheckedTextView(parent.getContext());
             textView.setText("the text for item "+position);
             textView.setTextColor(makeColorStateListForItem(position));
             return textView;
        }
    }

    private ColorStateList makeColorStateListForItem(int position){
        int pressedColor = pressedColorForItem(position);
        int checkedColor = checkedColorForItem(position);
        int defaultColor = defaultColorForItem(position);
        ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
                new int[][]{
                        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed},
                        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked},
                        new int[]{0},
                },
                new int[]{
                        pressedColor, //use when state is pressed
                        checkedColor, //use when state is checked, but not pressed
                        defaultColor}); //used when state is not pressed, nor checked 
    }

    private int pressedColorForItem(int position){
        //write your business logic to determine color here
        return ...;
    }

    private int checkedColorForItem(int position){
        //write your business logic to determine color here
        return ...;
    }

    private int defaultColorForItem(int position){
        return Color.WHITE;
    }

    //all other adapter methods
    //...
```

Note the use of `android.R.attr.state_checked` instead of the more intuitive `android.R.attr.state_selected` because the `state_selected` is not very precisely define with a touch screen (i.e. state_selected can give the expected behavior on the emulator, but on a real device it will probably fail)

On the other hand `state_checked` + [CheckedTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html) is going to work correctly on both simulator and real device.

Just call  [`List.setChoiceMode(...);`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setChoiceMode%28int%29) when initializing listView and [`ListView.setItemChecked`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setItemChecked%28int,%20boolean%29) in the clickListener.

```
final ListView listView = ...
listView.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter());
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        listView.setItemChecked(position,true);
    }
});
```

---

**EDIT** : to change the item background : just create a StateListDrawable instead of a simple ColorStateList :

```
private Drawable makeBackgroungForItem(int position){
    int pressedColor = pressedBackgroundColorForItem(position);
    int checkedColor = checkedBackgroundColorForItem(position);
    int defaultColor = defaultBackgroundColorForItem(position);
    StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
    stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_list_pressed}, new ColorDrawable(pressedColor));
    stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_list_checked}, new ColorDrawable(checkedColor));
    stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{0, new ColorDrawable(defaultColor));
    return stateListDrawable;
}
```

And in the `getView(...)`

```
textView.setBackground(makeBackgroungForItem(position));
```

Comment: This looks the most promising so far. Just going through it, why is the text color set in the beginning of `getView` as opposed to `setBackground`?

Comment: Also not 100% sure about the ListAdapter, since I am using an `ArrayAdapter<T>` but probably it's more or less the same

Comment: Regarding adapter : just extends ArrayAdapter (it will save you to write the implementation of some methods). Regarding background : the sample code here change the text color. A very similar solution can be build for the background (I'll edit my post to illustrate how to change the background color)

Comment: @Mahoni I just edited my post with more details on how to change the background with dynamic state-list

Comment: Works like a charm, much appreciate your thoroughness

Comment: I dont see how this is better than my solution, its a lot more code to write, but it achieves the same result - still using StateListDrawables, only here you define everything programatically instead of in XLM and use state_checked instead of state_selected, which, granded, might be better for your purpose. But otherwise, i dont think this is the best WAY of doing this.

Comment: @notrix Defining state-list in xml is OK (and indeed simpler) when you know the colors at compile time, but here the OP must deal with colors that are defined dynamically (i.e. as I understand "dynamically" : it means not known at compile time)

Comment: well both of our solutions are dynamic - and by the time the view is visible, the color is already set (so every time you press it, it will  be the same), just like my solution. the conditions that he uses to determine the color in your view can be used in my method just the same way and the result will be identical.

Comment: I disagree. In your solution you must define one selector per color (in your example only black and green are available). Assume the OP needs 10 different colors --> it means 10 selector ! (and if the list of possible colors is unknown at compile time you are forced to create the state-list programmatically)

Comment: @ben75 well ok. if the colors are unknown or there are a lot of them, then your way is better. That part was vague in the specs, though. But in case when only 3 or 4 colors are needed and they are already known (which is a fair assumption), my way is just easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say go with [state-aware drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html). Create a state-aware drawable XML file for each of the colors you want the background of your single ListView to be. Here is an example of state- aware Drawables called background_black.xml and background_green.xml. They makes your default background color white and while pressed/selected temporarily changes it to black or green. Both of these files go in your Drawable folder.

**background_black.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/black" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/black" />
</selector>
```

**background_green.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/green" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/green" />
</selector>
```

In your ListView item xml file, assign an ID to your root layout or whichever element is providing the visible background color. For this example, Ill assume its your root layout. Then in your Adapter's getView(), grab the element that you've assigned the id to and set one of the drawables you created with the color you want for its background. Like so:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
     //inflate your convertView, etc...
     ...
     ViewGroup baseLayout = (ViewGroup)convertView.findViewById(R.id.<your base layout id>);

     //these conditions need to reflect how you decide which list item gets which color
     if(position % 2 == 0){
         baseLayout.setBackground(R.drawable.background_black);
     } else {
         baseLayout.setBackground(R.drawable.background_green);
     //do whatever else you need
     ...
     return convertView;
}
```

NOTE: setBackground() is a new function, use setBackgroundDrawable() if coding for older versions of Android

Comment: I wish you had not answered that. Because I know that is the correct answer and I was gonna answer it myself to get the bounty. Oh well. Good job!

Comment: @notrix Nice, but what condition would I have to use to show my custom color on button press?

Comment: Thats totally up to you. I suppose it depends on which list items you want to have in a certain color. Ill update the answer to make all even items have black background, and all odd items to have some other background.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following approach:

- You need to create a `ListView` `Adapter` that supports **multiple different items**
- Each different Item class represents a different color and can have it's own implementation of how the pressed or selected state should be handled
- Since every `ListItem` will have it's own .xml layout file, you can specify the desired selector there

What you need:

- A **baseclass** `ListItem` that every item in the `ListView` inherits from
- This class provides abstract methods to get the `View` that represents the item and it's type
- If required, the `ListItem` class could have an `Integer` field mColor, that holds the color the item represents
- If required, the `ListItem` class could have a method to setup the selector with the speficied color

Example:

```
public abstract class ListItem {

    public static final int TYPE_WHATEVER_1                     = 0;
    public static final int TYPE_WHATEVER_2                     = 1;
    // and so on...

    /** the total number of list-item-types */
    public static final int TYPE_COUNT              = typecounthere;

    // if required for your implementation:
    protected int mColor;

    public abstract int getViewType();
    public abstract View getView(LayoutInflater inflater, View convertView);

    /** creates and sets the selector with your specified color */
    public void setupSelectorColor() {

        StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();

        ColorDrawable cdPressed = new ColorDrawable(mColor);
        ColorDrawable cdSelected = new ColorDrawable(mColor);
        ColorDrawable cdDefault = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        states.addState(new int[] {
                android.R.attr.state_pressed
        },
                cdPressed);
        states.addState(new int[] { 
                android.R.attr.state_selected
        },
                cdSelected);
        states.addState(new int[] {},
                cdDefault);

        setBackgroundDrawable(states);
    }
}
```

- For each color, create a subclass of `ListItem`
- Inside the `getView(...)` method, inflate your desired layout
- Don't forget to return the correct type in the `getViewType()` method
- Do whatever you want with your color in here
- Setup the selector with your color

Example:

```
public class ItemTypeOne extends ListItem {

    public ItemTypeOne(int color) {
        mColor = color;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewType() {
            // return the type
        return TYPE_WHATEVER_1;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(LayoutInflater inflater, View convertView) {

        if(convertView == null) {
            // inflate the layout 
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_type_one, null);
        }    

        // setup the selector
        setupSelectorColor();

        // do other stuff

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

- An adapter that supports different item types

Example:

```
public class ListItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListItem> {

    public ListItemAdapter(Context context, List<ListItem> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getItem(position).getView(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()), convertView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return getItem(position).getViewType();
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return ListItem.TYPE_COUNT;
    }
}
```

Putting it all together:

```
ArrayList<ListItem> list = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
// fill the list
list.add(new ItemTypeOne(somecolor));
list.add(new ItemTypeTwo(somecolor));
list.add(new ItemTypeOne(somecolor));
list.add(new ItemTypeWhatever(somecolor));

ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

ListItemAdapter a = new ListItemAdapter(Context, list);         
lv.setAdapter(a);
```

Concerning `CustomViews` and **selectors and their behaviour**, I suggest reading this question (and answer): **[How to implement a CustomView with custom selector states?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21930562/how-to-implement-a-customview-with-custom-selector-states/21969864#21969864)**

Answer (score -1):

I'd say don't overcomplicate this. It can be simple as create an array of `int` that will contain possible colors, and set them to each item using `Random` class.

```
// This goes inside hosting fragment or activity
listview.setOnItemClickListner( new OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           if(view.isSelected()){
               view.setSelected(false);
               // also maybe change bg color back to normal?
           }

           else {
                // This one for always a different color
                view.setBackgroundColor(adapter.getColor());

                // This is for foreground color change instead of background
                FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.my_frame_layout);

                final Drawable drawable = new ColorDrawable( /*  your getColor() function  */ );
                frameLayout.setForeground(drawable);

                // This one for alwyas the same color for the row at position given by {@param position}
                view.setBackgroundColor(adapter.getColor(position));
                view.setSelected(true);
           }
      }
});



// All this goes inside your custom listview Adapter
int[] colors = {
      R.colors.red,
      R.colors.blue,
      ...
}

Random random = new Random();

// If each time the selection will bring a different color, use this implementation
public int getColor() {
    return colors[random.nextInt(colors.length)]; 
}

// If each row should have different color, but always the same color for a row then use this one instead
SparseIntArray spa = new SparseIntArray();
public int getColor(int position) {
     if(spa.get(position) == 0) {
         // the color hasnt been created for that row yet
         spa.put(position, colors[random.nextInt(colors.length)];
     }

     return spa.get(position);     
}
```

**Edit: ** now, if what you want is a foreground selection, then your row should have a `FrameLayout` container, and you should change it's 'android:foreground' property:

```
final Drawable drawable = new ColorDrawable( /*  your getColor() function  */ );
frameLayout.setForeground(drawable);
```