# Navigation view item different icon colors for different items

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I am using navigation view , I want to put different colored icons for different items for unselected items and white colored icon for selected item.

I am using menu for items, I have seen below example for could not apply for my problem

[Different select colors for different list view items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285185/different-select-colors-for-different-list-view-items)

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different select colors for different list view items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285185/different-select-colors-for-different-list-view-items)

Comment: @Farside I already mentioned I have seen that and could not apply for my problem

Comment: Sanyasirao, can you elaborate more, what can't be applied, what prevents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add different colored icon into drawable directory.

**Remove navigation default color on icons by programmatically**

```
mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

**By XML**

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
...
app:itemIconTint="null" 
... />
```

To set white Color on selected item

Create drawable resource file under drawable directory with **Selector** and add below code.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="Your color" />
</selector>
```

Comment: it makes all items icons as white if item not selected, but I want different colored icons for different items

Comment: but it gives same color "Your color" all unselected items, but I want to give different colors for each unselected item

Comment: Share your screen..You can set a color ex. red for not selected item or add different colored icon in res

Answer (score 0):

1.put your icons into drawable-xx file.
2.new one android-xml-file named 'selector_btn',android choose 'selector' type for it.
3.code it like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/black" />
<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/black" />
```

4.in your menu layout, set background for your button.