# Setting border to circular imageview is not working when paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));

Tags: android, canvas, imageview, paint, geometry

I want to set border to circular Image view and also want the image view to be inside the circle, so below is my code-

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedRectBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
        Bitmap result = null;
        try {
            result = Bitmap.createBitmap(pixels, pixels, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, pixels*2, pixels*2);

           // paint.setAntiAlias(true);
          //;  canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);

            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawCircle(pixels/2, pixels/2, pixels/2, paint);

            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(15);
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#17B3F0"));
            canvas.drawCircle(pixels/2+0.7f, pixels/2+0.7f, pixels/2+0.1f, paint);


            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError o) {
        }
        return result;
    }
```

So the problem is with the line 
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));

If I am commenting this line, it's making all the properties added to paint object visible but making image comes out of the circle.
But I want the Image to be inside the circle as well as a border to be set.
Any help is appreciated.Thanks.

**Updated from Here -**

I have created a custom class which MyCustomAdapter and Inside getView I am setting the imageView onStateChangeListener as below -

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        View view = inflater.inflate(type == List_Section ? R.layout.section : R.layout.listitem, parent, false);

        if (type == List_Section) {
            departments = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_li_section));
            departments.setText(list_complete_data.get(position).toString());
        } else {
            //StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = (StateListDrawable) view.getBackground();
          Emp_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emp_name);
            Emp_number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emp_no);
            small_profile =(CircleImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.small_profile);
            Log.e(TAG,"small_profile====="+small_profile);
            Log.e(TAG,"inside getView=====");

           small_profile.setOnStateChangedListener(new OnStateChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStateChanged(int state) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"onStateistener and  state=="+state+".,,,R.attr.state_on==="+R.attr.state_on+",,,R.attr.state_off=="+R.attr.state_off);
                    switch (state){
                        case R.attr.state_on :
                            small_profile.setBorderColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                            break;
                        case R.attr.state_off:
                            small_profile.setBorderColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT :** I have made some changes to the code according to your requirements:

add the following interface to your project:

```
public interface OnStateChangeListener {
    void onStateChanged(int state);
}
```

and then make then I made some changes in the `CircleImageView`

```
public class CircleImageView extends ImageView implements View.OnTouchListener {

private static final int[] mStates = { R.attr.state_notset, R.attr.state_on, R.attr.state_off };
    private int mStateIndex = 0; // first state is "notset"

    private OnStateChangeListener mListener;
    private static final ScaleType SCALE_TYPE = ScaleType.CENTER_CROP;

    private static final Bitmap.Config BITMAP_CONFIG = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    private static final int COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION = 2;

    private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH = 0;
    private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
    private static final int DEFAULT_FILL_COLOR = Color.TRANSPARENT;
    private static final boolean DEFAULT_BORDER_OVERLAY = false;

    private final RectF mDrawableRect = new RectF();
    private final RectF mBorderRect = new RectF();

    private final Matrix mShaderMatrix = new Matrix();
    private final Paint mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
    private final Paint mBorderPaint = new Paint();
    private final Paint mFillPaint = new Paint();

    private int mBorderColor = DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR;
    private int mBorderWidth = DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH;
    private int mFillColor = DEFAULT_FILL_COLOR;

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private BitmapShader mBitmapShader;
    private int mBitmapWidth;
    private int mBitmapHeight;

    private float mDrawableRadius;
    private float mBorderRadius;

    private ColorFilter mColorFilter;

    private boolean mReady;
    private boolean mSetupPending;
    private boolean mBorderOverlay;

    public CircleImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init();
    }

    public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CircleImageView, defStyle, 0);

        mBorderWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_border_width, DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH);
        mBorderColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_border_color, DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);
        mBorderOverlay = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_border_overlay, DEFAULT_BORDER_OVERLAY);
        mFillColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_fill_color, DEFAULT_FILL_COLOR);

        a.recycle();

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        super.setScaleType(SCALE_TYPE);
        mReady = true;

        if (mSetupPending) {
            setup();
            mSetupPending = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ScaleType getScaleType() {
        return SCALE_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public void setScaleType(ScaleType scaleType) {
        if (scaleType != SCALE_TYPE) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("ScaleType %s not supported.", scaleType));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdjustViewBounds(boolean adjustViewBounds) {
        if (adjustViewBounds) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("adjustViewBounds not supported.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mBitmap == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (mFillColor != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
            canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2.0f, getHeight() / 2.0f, mDrawableRadius, mFillPaint);
        }
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2.0f, getHeight() / 2.0f, mDrawableRadius, mBitmapPaint);
        if (mBorderWidth != 0) {
            canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2.0f, getHeight() / 2.0f, mBorderRadius, mBorderPaint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        setup();
    }

    public int getBorderColor() {
        return mBorderColor;
    }

    public void setBorderColor(@ColorInt int borderColor) {
        if (borderColor == mBorderColor) {
            return;
        }

        mBorderColor = borderColor;
        mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setBorderColorResource(@ColorRes int borderColorRes) {
        setBorderColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(borderColorRes));
    }

    public int getFillColor() {
        return mFillColor;
    }

    public void setFillColor(@ColorInt int fillColor) {
        if (fillColor == mFillColor) {
            return;
        }

        mFillColor = fillColor;
        mFillPaint.setColor(fillColor);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setFillColorResource(@ColorRes int fillColorRes) {
        setFillColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(fillColorRes));
    }

    public int getBorderWidth() {
        return mBorderWidth;
    }

    public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth) {
        if (borderWidth == mBorderWidth) {
            return;
        }

        mBorderWidth = borderWidth;
        setup();
    }

    public boolean isBorderOverlay() {
        return mBorderOverlay;
    }

    public void setBorderOverlay(boolean borderOverlay) {
        if (borderOverlay == mBorderOverlay) {
            return;
        }

        mBorderOverlay = borderOverlay;
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
        super.setImageBitmap(bm);
        mBitmap = bm;
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        super.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        mBitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(drawable);
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageResource(@DrawableRes int resId) {
        super.setImageResource(resId);
        mBitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(getDrawable());
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageURI(Uri uri) {
        super.setImageURI(uri);
        mBitmap = uri != null ? getBitmapFromDrawable(getDrawable()) : null;
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        if (cf == mColorFilter) {
            return;
        }

        mColorFilter = cf;
        applyColorFilter();
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public ColorFilter getColorFilter() {
        return mColorFilter;
    }

    private void applyColorFilter() {
        if (mBitmapPaint != null) {
            mBitmapPaint.setColorFilter(mColorFilter);
        }
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        if (drawable == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        }

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap;

            if (drawable instanceof ColorDrawable) {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION, COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION, BITMAP_CONFIG);
            } else {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), BITMAP_CONFIG);
            }

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            drawable.draw(canvas);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void setup() {
        if (!mReady) {
            mSetupPending = true;
            return;
        }

        if (getWidth() == 0 && getHeight() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        if (mBitmap == null) {
            invalidate();
            return;
        }

        mBitmapShader = new BitmapShader(mBitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        mBitmapPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mBitmapPaint.setShader(mBitmapShader);

        mBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mBorderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor);
        mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(mBorderWidth);

        mFillPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mFillPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mFillPaint.setColor(mFillColor);

        mBitmapHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
        mBitmapWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();

        mBorderRect.set(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        mBorderRadius = Math.min((mBorderRect.height() - mBorderWidth) / 2.0f, (mBorderRect.width() - mBorderWidth) / 2.0f);

        mDrawableRect.set(mBorderRect);
        if (!mBorderOverlay) {
            mDrawableRect.inset(mBorderWidth, mBorderWidth);
        }
        mDrawableRadius = Math.min(mDrawableRect.height() / 2.0f, mDrawableRect.width() / 2.0f);

        applyColorFilter();
        updateShaderMatrix();
        invalidate();
    }

    private void updateShaderMatrix() {
        float scale;
        float dx = 0;
        float dy = 0;

        mShaderMatrix.set(null);

        if (mBitmapWidth * mDrawableRect.height() > mDrawableRect.width() * mBitmapHeight) {
            scale = mDrawableRect.height() / (float) mBitmapHeight;
            dx = (mDrawableRect.width() - mBitmapWidth * scale) * 0.5f;
        } else {
            scale = mDrawableRect.width() / (float) mBitmapWidth;
            dy = (mDrawableRect.height() - mBitmapHeight * scale) * 0.5f;
        }

        mShaderMatrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        mShaderMatrix.postTranslate((int) (dx + 0.5f) + mDrawableRect.left, (int) (dy + 0.5f) + mDrawableRect.top);

        mBitmapShader.setLocalMatrix(mShaderMatrix);
    }

    @Override
    public int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace+1);

        int [] state = { mStates[mStateIndex] };

        mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, state);

        return drawableState;
    }

    public void setOnStateChangedListener(OnStateChangeListener l) {
        this.mListener = l;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.e("STATETOUCH", "onTouch: down");
                mStateIndex = 1;
                if(mListener != null) mListener.onStateChanged(mStates[1]);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.e("STATETOUCH", "onTouch: up");
                mStateIndex = 2;
                if(mListener != null) mListener.onStateChanged(mStates[2]);
                return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
 }
```

**EDIT** in `attrs.xml`:

and this in `attrs.xml`

```
<declare-styleable name="CircleImageView">
        <attr name="civ_border_width" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="civ_border_color" format="color" />
        <attr name="civ_border_overlay" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="civ_fill_color" format="color" />
        <attr name="state_on" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="state_off" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

and use it like this in your code :

```
<com.yourpackagename.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:id="@+id/img"
        app:civ_border_width="1dp"
        app:civ_border_color="#000"
        android:src="@drawable/profile_pic"/>
```

and then in your code do the following:

```
yourImageView.setOnStateChangedListener(new OnStateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(int state) {
                switch (state){
                    case R.attr.state_on:
                        yourImageView.setBorderColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
                        break;
                    case R.attr.state_off:
                        yourImageView.setBorderColor(Color.parseColor("#ff00ff"));
                    //do anything you would do after onclick of this imageview here, like open a new activity.
                        break;
                }

                Log.e("STATECHANGE", "State changed to: " + context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(state));
            }
        });
```

reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21969864/2251837

[image: works fine for me]

As you can see this code works fine for me. Can you post your code, how you did it, then may be I will be able to help?

**EDIT:** This is what you need to change in your `getView()` method :

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { // here view is this view : View view = inflater.inflate(type == List_Section ? R.layout.section : R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                small_profile.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you please tell me a way to change the border color of circular imageview when listview items is in pressed state ?

Comment: Check my updated answer, let me know if any further query.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have added your updated code but it made no changes for me.

Comment: myImageView.setOnStateChangedListener(new OnStateChangeListener() {}  is not calling for me at all.

Comment: I added an image for your reference that this code works fine for me, can you post the code of how you did it?

Comment: every thing is similar as your code except one thing , that I am calling myImageView.setOnStateChangedListener(new OnStateChangeListener() {}  inside getView method of My Custom Adapter.Below is the code -

Comment: did you test it when clicking on the CircleImageView on the ListView item, or when clicking the whole Listview item? (P.s. I have tested this with RecyclerView instead of ListView)

Comment: No I haven't checked it by clicking on CircleImageView bcz at the end I want the border color to be changed on listItem click.

Comment: Okay, I have updated my answer , please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw 2 bitmap here to activate Xfermode:

```
private Bitmap maskingImage(Bitmap s1, Bitmap s2) {
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(s2.getWidth(), s2.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(result);
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    mCanvas.drawBitmap(s1, 0, 0, null);
    mCanvas.drawBitmap(s2, 0, 0, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(null);
    return result;
}
```

s2 is ur circle, s1 is ur image. If you want to change to Mode.SRC_IN, just swap s1 and s2 param position